# shade between two concentric objects

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm trying to shade (transition from one color to another color) between two concentric objects with happen to be rectangles, while producing multiple concentric objects in a `\foreach` loop.

I can produce the multiple concentric objects using `\node` and using `\draw`.  Using `draw`, I can shade the outer object using `\shadedraw`, and `\fill` the inner object using `fill=white`.  Unfortunately, the shading goes from the center, but I want the shading to go from the boundary of the inner object.  I want the shading to transition from inner (red) to outer (blue)

Any suggestion on using `draw`, `shadedraw`, or `node`?

Here's my Minimal Working Example using `pdflatex`, and the output is below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\x{7.5}
        \def\z{0.25}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{6.5-2*\z}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{5.0-2*\z}
        \foreach \y in {0, 1}  {
        \node[draw, rectangle, rounded corners=5ex, blue!40, minimum width=6.5 cm, minimum height=5 cm] (rect01) at (3.25+\y*\x,2.5) {};
        \node[draw, rectangle, rounded corners=4ex, red!40, minimum width=\xx cm, minimum height=\yy cm] (rect01) at (3.25+\y*\x,2.5) {};
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\x{7.5}
        \def\z{0.25}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{6.5-2*\z}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{5.0-2*\z}
        \foreach \y in {0, 1}  {
        \shadedraw[inner color=red!40, outer color=blue!40, draw=blue!40, rounded corners=5ex] (\y*\x, 0.0) rectangle (6.5+\y*\x, 10.0);
        \draw[red!40, fill=white, rounded corners=4ex] (\y*\x+2*\z, 0.0+2*\z) rectangle (6.5+\y*\x-2*\z, 10.0-2*\z);
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT BELOW is in response to Black Mild's very nice suggestion of combining `\fill` with a couple of `\def`s.

`\fill` has two features with are incompatible with the situation I stated.  One feature I can work around, the other feature I cannot.

- The fading by `\fill` is radially symmetric: **cannot** work around
  this feature.
- `\fill` also fades from the center of the concentric shapes to the
  edge of the larger shape: **can** work around this by adjusting the
  color transparency.

Essentially, `\fill` will paint the entire area of the larger figure, and do so with radial symmetry from the center of the figure.  Defining the paths separately is a nice procedure for radially symmetric shapes, but not for rectangles.

See the figure below for the effect on rectangles and the work around for adjusting color transparency.

[image: Solution_using_fill]

1. `\def\incurve{(2,-3) circle(0.5)}
    \def\outcurve{(2,-3) circle(2)}
    \fill[inner color=red!40, outer color=blue!40,even odd rule] \incurve \outcurve;`
2. `\def\incurveTwo{(7,-3) circle(1.5)}
    \def\outcurveTwo{(7,-3) circle(2)}
    \fill[inner color=red!40, outer color=blue!40,even odd rule] \incurveTwo \outcurveTwo;`
3. `\def\incurveThree{(12,-3) circle(1.75)}
    \def\outcurveThree{(12,-3) circle(2)}
    \fill[inner color=red!80, outer color=blue!20,even odd rule] \incurveThree \outcurveThree;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for you,  using `fill` only.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\incurve{(0,0) circle(1)}
\def\outcurve{(0,0) circle(2)}
\fill[inner color=red!40, outer color=blue!40,even odd rule] \incurve \outcurve;
\draw[red] \incurve; 
\draw[blue] \outcurve;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There is a cheat that works in this case only: draw many circles with suitable colors and radii.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\def\incurve{(0,0) circle(1)} 
\def\outcurve{(0,0) circle(2)} 
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,100} 
\draw[blue!\i!red] (0,0) circle(1+.01*\i); 
\draw[red] \incurve; 
\draw[blue] \outcurve; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that `evenodd` rule in Asymptote works very well for this kind of filling. Resulting picture is almost identical to the above "cheat" one.

[image]

```
% asy.exe -f pdf -noView "xxx".asy
% by Le Quoc Hiep  
unitsize(1cm);
real r1=1, r2=2;
path incurve=scale(r1)*unitcircle;
path outcurve=scale(r2)*unitcircle;
radialshade(incurve^^outcurve,red+evenodd,(0,0),r1,blue,(0,0),r2);
shipout(bbox(5mm,Fill(white)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion using `\fill`.  It works for circles in your example, but not rectangles, the shape I specified in my question.  Also, there's some work around needed because `\fill` fades from the center as I showed in my edit to the question.  Thanks anyways, though.

Comment: @DavidCollins an interesting question! let us try more

Comment: @DavidCollins How about this cheat? `\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\incurve{(0,0) circle(1)}
\def\outcurve{(0,0) circle(2)}
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,100}
\draw[blue!\i!red] (0,0) circle(1+.01*\i);
\draw[red] \incurve; 
\draw[blue] \outcurve;
\end{tikzpicture}
`

Comment: Thanks!  That almost got me there.  Nice solution nonetheless.  I needed to use`\pgfmathsetmacro{\ii}{{5-\i/100}` to handle the rounded corners.  This fix worked well for solid colors: blue to red.  However, for `blue!40` to `red!40`, another set of `\pgfmathsetmacro{\ii}{40-\i/100*40}` & `\pgfmathsetmacro{\jj}{\i/100*40}`was needed.  The interaction between `\pgfmathsetmacro` and `rounded corners` was fine.  However, the interaction between `\pgfmathsetmacro` and 'blue!\ii!\i\!red!\jj` or even 'blue!\i\!red!\jj` was not.

Comment: I accepted to answer since it largely took care of the issue I presented.  I figured that final touch is the source for another question once I work out a MWE.  Maybe I'll even get it solved while creating the MWE.  But until then there is far more work to do creating this climate change board game.  Thanks Again!!

Comment: @DavidCollins I add more code, and a remark about `evenodd` in Asymptote